# Division by 0 within a map function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, divide-by-zero

I am wondering how to handle the division by 0 error inside a map function (under Python 2.7).

Without using `map`, I get

```
def my_func(a, b):
    return a / b

a = pandas.DataFrame([1, 1])
b = pandas.DataFrame([1, 0])

my_func(a, b)
Out[]: 
          0
0  1.000000
1       inf
```

but I get a different result when using `map`:

```
map(my_func, a, b)
Out[]:
File "<ipython-input-12-83b4adbfd8de>", line 3, in func
return a / b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: You can make sure NumPy's division is always used with `return np.divide(a, b)`

Comment: @jdjdehesa, indeed I don't have any error with this method, only a warning. However, the output of `map(my_func, a, b)` is `Out[28]: [0]`

Comment: Or similarly `return np.asarray(a) / np.asarray(b)`

Comment: I don't understand why the output is `Out[]: [0]`?

Comment: Ah well, the thing is `map(my_func, a, b)` will actually iterate through the column labels of `a` and `b`. In your example both `a` and `b` have the same list of columns, `[0]`, so actually what I get as output in my console is `[nan]` (`0 / 0`). You may pass instead `a[0], b[0]` or `a.values, b.values` or something else...

Comment: indeed, using `.values` solved the problem. TY

Answer (score 1):

You could try in this way:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    if b != 0: return a / b
    else: return np.inf
```

Or catching the warning with:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

def my_func(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b
    except:
        return np.inf
```

Comment: This is not really correct for 0/0 though (which should be NaN), or for cases that should return minus infinity (if either `a` is negative or `b` is `-0`).